# Why Symfony doesnt autowire mailer, router?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Im using Symfony 4. I want to use Router and mailer in my services. I am including them using Dependency injection.

```
public function __construct(Swift_Mailer $mailer, EngineInterface $templating, RouterInterface $router)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->templating = $templating;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
argument "$templating" of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface" but no such service exists. It cannot be auto-registered because it is from a different root namespace. Did you create a class that implements this interface?
```

Any hint to use Mailer, Router services in Symfony 4 ?

Comment: Does `bin/console debug:autowiring | grep Engine` list the interface you’re looking for?

Answer (score 7):

I had to `composer require symfony/templating`in order to get the `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface` service.

Also the following configuration has to be added under `framework`:

`templating:
        enabled: false
        engines: ['twig']`

Comment: Wow just adding `templating` section under `framework` worked for me

Comment: same for me but I have to anabled to true

Comment: Thanks s lot bro saved my day +1

Answer (score 5):

Change the TypeHint and use Interface, the autowire work with interface type hint

try this :

```
public function __construct(Swift_Mailer $mailer, \Twig_Environment $templating, RouterInterface $router)
```

Comment: I have corrected the question. Its working for Symfony 3. EngineInterface gives problem while injecting into my service. You are correct for RouterInterface though.

Comment: Please read the question.  The questioner did not write it for fun.  Sorry.  Never could resist throwing rocks at glass houses.  In any event, you might consider suggest installing and configuring the templating component which no longer happens by default and then giving the correct typehint.  Just saying.

Comment: FYI,I have installed twig and templating for symfony. Its just the EngineInterface causing the problem

Comment: this would not work in all cases, because the engineInterface is different from Twig\Environment